# Is there a way to "trick" virtual server to think it has keyboard?

Tags: java, selenium, amazon-ec2, automation

The question is in the title.
A little bit more information:
I'm trying to run automation script on AWS EC2 server(Windows 2008 R2 server).
I'm using Selenium to automate some flow with chrome driver.
The problem is - when i try to use Robot to press keyboard keys it doesn't work...
also tried autoit/autoitx.

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Did you have a look at [Actions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) Class ?

Comment: Or did you try `sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);`? I highly discourage usage of `Robot` unless it's necessary.

Comment: @DebanjanB Actions class can't send keyboard keys, it can only press on elements like buttons or other clickable items. sendKeys doesn't work when you don't have physical keyboard connected because it's like Robot, it uses the port of the physical keyboard.